# PILの”ImportError: No module named Image"を解決したい

Tags: python, macos, pil

Pythonで生じる`ImportError: No module named Image`について質問させていただきます。

MacOS (10.9.5 Mavericks) でPython (2.7.10) を使用し、画像処理のためにPIL (1.1.7) を利用しています (インストールは全てMacportsでしています)。これまでのプログラムに別のライブラリをimportして実行したところ、

> import Image ImportError: No module named Image

がでました。

追加したライブラリ開発者に問い合わせたところ、ライブラリと一緒にインストールするためのPIL がPython2.5用だったので、2.7で動作するPILを新しくインストールすれば解決すると回答されました。
しかし、PIL (Python2.7用) はすでにインストール済みであり、問題なく動作します。

インストール済みのライブラリをMacports調べたところ、

> py27-pil @1.1.7_7 
>   py27-Pillow @2.9.0_1

と確認もできました。
ただ、上記のようにPILはactiveではありませんでした (他ライブラリはactive)。
また、再度インストールしようとすると。

> $ sudo port install py27-pil ---> Computing dependencies for py27-pil
>   ---> Activating py27-pil @1.1.7_7 Error: org.macports.activate for port py27-pil returned: Image error:
>   /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pilconvert.py
>   already exists and does not belong to a registered port. Unable to
>   activate port py27-pil. Use 'port -f activate py27-pil' to force the
>   activation. Please see the log file for port py27-pil for details:
>   /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_python_py-pil/py27-pil/main.log
>   To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
>   http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets Error: Processing of port
>   py27-pil failed

と表示されました。

この場合、PILを強制的にactiveにすれば解決するでしょうか。

ご教示お願いいたします。

---

**追記**

`import PIl`や`import Image`を`from PIL import Image`に変えてみましたが、エラーは解消されませんでした。

Comment: 色々インストールしたせいで依存関係がぐちゃぐちゃなので一回 MacPorts の py27-pil と py27-Pillow をアンインストールして pip で Pillow を入れてみてはいかがでしょうか。自分はそれで使えるようになりました。

Comment: @pixy  アンインストール後、pipでpillowを入れようとすると`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PIllow in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...`と表示されます (pipでもすでにインストール済みです)。

Comment: ログ中に
`Use 'port -f activate py27-pil' to force the
activation.`
とありますが, このコマンドは試してみましたか?

Comment: @cocoatomo 再起動後、強制的にactiveすることで解決できました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @Rikka 自己解決なさったようで良かったです. では, 自己解決した内容を回答として記入しておいてください.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errorにある、

> port -f activate py27-pil

を使用したところ、PILがactiveになり、解決しました。